# How to define method with optional argument and argument unpacking?

Tags: python, python-2.7, optional-parameters, iterable-unpacking

I have a question regarding how to define and call a method with both optional arguments and with a *args parameter in Python. For example,

```
def test_func(arg1, optional_arg=None, *args):
    ...
```

And I want to be able to call the method with either of the following statements:

```
test_func("foo", arg1, arg2, ..., optional_arg="bar")
...
test_func("foo", arg1, arg2, ...) 
# arg1, arg2 ... belongs to *args;
# optional_arg is unset (defaults to None)
```

Is this possible at all, or do I always have to set optional_arg to something when calling a method like this? I.e. I only want optional_arg to be set when I specifically write optional_arg=... when calling the function.

Comment: That's what `**kwargs` are for.

Comment: In addition to answers below, note that in Python 3 you can use [keyword-only arguments](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [**kwargs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) for that.

```
def test_func(arg1, *args, **kwargs):
    optional_arg = kwargs.get('optional_arg')
    ...
```

The only limitation is that the keyworded argument (optional_arg) must always be after keywordless arguments

```
>>> test_func("foo", optional_arg="bar", arg1, arg2, ...)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
>>> test_func("foo", arg1, arg2, ..., optional_arg="bar")
...
>>> test_func("foo", arg1, arg2, ...)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the positional arguments force you to specify a value for the named argument even if it has a default value; you cannot get around this.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the keyword arguments must come last in a function call, you can't call `test_func` as you did in your first example, optional_arg="bar" must come after all non-keyword arguments.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out; I actually meant to write it in the order you said in the first example (edited the OP now). My problem was mainly with the second example and if it's possible to call it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this kind of workaround:

```
def test_func(arg1, *args,**optional_arg):
    print arg1 
    print args 
    if 'optional_arg' in optional_arg:
        print optional_arg['optional_arg'] 

test_func("foo", 'v','n',optional_arg="bar")

test_func("foo",'v','n')
```